Ajuda com idéia de projeto na Godot
O projeto consiste em criar um jogo educacional na Godot que ensine programação por meio de blocos de instruções simples no estilo Scratch, queria idéias de como fazer isso ou qual passo a passo deveria seguir. Pesquisei pela internet e não encontrei se alguém fez algo parecido, se tiverem idéias para me ajudar agradeço :)
